# "sudo yum install nginx" throws "Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository"

Tags: linux, yum, nginx

Here's what I get when I type it in via the command line:

```
[prompt]$ sudo yum install nginx
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
http://nginx.org/packages/rhel/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: nginx. Please verify its path and try again
```

I tried creating a /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo file as [described here](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) but got the same thing. Any ideas?

I'm running "Amazon Linux AMI release 2012.09".

Comment: Never mind... nginx.repo existed but was empty. Deleting it seems to have fixed it..

Comment: you should answer this yourself and accept the answer, to close this out.

Answer (score 2):

I also caught that problem, try this:

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
```

Change the repo site:

```
[nginx] 
name=nginx repo 
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=0 
enabled=1
```

So: http://nginx.org/packages/**centos**/**6**/$basearch/

Please read the instructions completely:

> Due to differences between how CentOS, RHEL, and Scientific Linux populate the
>      $releasever variable, it is necessary to manually replace $releasever with either 
>      "5" (for 5.x) or "6" (for 6.x), depending upon your OS version.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/531045/nginx-repomd-xml-404-not-found